# Problem with Mahito's Domain Expansion

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

I recently read Jujutsu Kaisen manga and therein **Mahito copied Satoru's domain expansion** technique.

When Satoru used his domain expansion technique for a fraction of second in a crowded place, all those who got affected by it had lots of information flowing through their brain and so they were in a state of trance.

Later, while fighting Yuuji and Aoi, Mahito also reproduces the same results on Yuuji and Aoi via domain expansion for a fraction of second (as he did not want to upset Sukuna) despite the differences between the techniques of Mahito and Satoru.

While in the case of Satoru, literally endless information flows through a person's brain, that's not so in the case of Mahito. So, **there should not have been any trance/oblivion effect** on either of them. Since Mahito affects the shape of the soul, so, any effect should have wore off the moment the domain expansion technique ended.

I tried to convince myself with this: Mahito, in that fraction of second, may have, on a very small level changed the soul's shape of both of them which took time to adjust back to normal later on. But the problem is, this still shouldn't have affected Yuuji as he is aware of his soul's shape and also had Sukuna within himself. 
Also, I guess it's reasonable to assume that there's a very high chance that Aoi is aware of his soul's shape too. Though it doesn't matter as I actually read as "copying/learning from Satoru".

Am I right in saying that Akutami (author of manga) missed this minor detail or did I not understand properly what he was trying to convey/show?

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga Stack Exchange. While entertainment-related SE sites are relatively more lax than technical/scientific sites, open-ended question is still discouraged. So, considering the current question "*What are your thoughts on this (from my perspective) anomaly?*" is a bit unclear, could you [edit] and clarify the question more explicitly? Thanks.

Comment: @AkiTanaka thanks a lot for your warm welcome and for giving me the clarification that was very much required to be present in my question :-)